# How can jQuery/JavaScript code export table to CSV file regardless of the table's size. look @ jsfiddle link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, export-to-csv

Below is a link that display table and code

http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/485/

that displays the issue with code I'm having with getting table to export to excel CSV. When I click the the export button the CSV file gets generated but the file is blank with no data.

---

// JS code on jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
  }

  // This must be a hyperlink
  $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    // CSV
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

    // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
  });
});
```

Comment: works in firefox although there is alot of space wrapped around the values, might want to trim it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are putting a div with the dvData id around your table.